# How do I resolve this Bundler error when upgrading from Rails 3.2.13 to 3.2.15?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I'm trying to upgrade from Rails 3.2.13 to 3.2.15.

Old Gemfile

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
```

New Gemfile

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.15'
```

When I run bundle, I get this:

```
$ bundle
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/......
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    activesupport (3.2.13)

  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 3.2.15) ruby depends on
      activesupport (= 3.2.15) ruby

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.
```

The [advice I found online](http://ryanbigg.com/2011/01/why-you-should-run-bundle-update/) is to run `bundle update rails` to fix this issue, but that will update to Rails 4.0.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Remove `Gemfile.lock` and do bundle again.

Comment: Won't that mean that other gems will potentially get updated?

Comment: So maybe add max versions to gems which you don't want to upgrade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `bundle update` won't update Rails to 4.0 when you have 3.2.1.5 specified in the Gemfile. It does not change your `Gemfile`, only `Gemfile.lock`.

Answer (score 1):

You can run bundle update rails, it won't mess with the other gems.